# Slide over carousel, with fluid widths

Tags: jquery, slideshow, show-hide, carousel

I have this markup:

```
<section id="content">
  <a class="back">Back</a>
  <a class="forward"/>Forward</a>

  <article>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </article>

  <article>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </article>

  <article>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </article>

</section>
```

Where the article's content is of a variety of heights, and the whole layout sits in a fluid container. I'd like to set this up so that the back and forward links would cycle through all the articles under content, and also loop infinitely. Icing on the cake would be transitions to animate from right to left for forward, and from left to right on previous,

Just not sure how, would REALLY appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Nivo Slider plugin before for something similar.  It's very easy to use and easy to set up.  And it's free!  You can download it here:

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

The tutorial for installing it is here:

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

Comment: This is a great, actually worked fine for the image section I'm doing... but I this is just text, wondering if there is a resource for sliding text containers.

Comment: You can put text/html in there as well as images!  It just cycles through the nodes.  An example might be:

[code]<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
        <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
        <div>My text here</div>
    </div>
</div>[/code]

Comment: Sorry about the lack of code tags - Not sure of the syntax for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a Simple Infinite Carousel with jQuery](http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery)

I copied the code to jsfiddle for you to check out

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/h9X6Y/)